# @Mock jpaRepository calls real save method in other hand @MockBean calls mocked method

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I thought I understood difference between `@Mock` and `@MockBean` even I thought any object mocked never call real methods, Although when I run below test I can see basket has been inserted on hsqldb logs. So now I feel a bit confused about why basket is inserted when `@Mock` is used and not inserted when `@MockBean` is used.

```
INSERT INTO BASKET VALUES(5,'ABCDEFGHIJ','ACTIVE',1,'2019-01-18 12:00:36.066000','2019-01-18 12:00:36.066000')
```

In other hand if I do instead then hsqldb are clean. In both cases test is successfull.

```
@MockBean
private BasketRepository basketRepo;
```

**Test class**

```
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@SpringBootTest( )
@ActiveProfiles( "test" )
public class BasketServiceTests
{

@SpyBean
private BasketService basketService;

@Mock
private BasketRepository basketRepo;

@Autowired
private UserAccountRepository userAccountRepo;

@Test
public void createBasketWithSameOrderRef() throws Exception
{
    UserAccount customer = userAccountRepo.findById( 1 )
            .orElseThrow( () -> new NotFoundException( "Customer not found" ) );

    Basket basket = new Basket();
    basket.setAudit( new Audit() );
    basket.setOrderRef( "ABCDEFGHIJ" );
    basket.setStatus( BasketStatusEnum.ACTIVE );
    basket.setUserAccount( customer );

    when( basketRepo.existsByOrderRef( anyString() ) ).thenReturn( false );
    when( basketRepo.save( isA( Basket.class ) ) ).thenReturn( basket );
    when( basketService.createOrderReference( ) ).thenReturn( "ABCDEFGHIJ" );

    Assert.notNull( basketService.getOrCreateByUserAccountBasket( customer ), "Basket id is null" );

}
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class BasketService 
{
@Autowired
private BasketRepository basketRepo;

public Basket getOrCreateByUserAccountBasket( @NotNull final UserAccount userAccount )
{
    Optional<Basket> optBasket = basketRepo.findByUserAccountAndStatusActive( userAccount );

    if ( optBasket.isPresent() )
    {
        return optBasket.get();
    }

    String orderRef = null;

    do
    {
        orderRef = createOrderReference();
    }
    while( basketRepo.existsByOrderRef( orderRef ) );

    Basket basket = new Basket();
    basket.setAudit( new Audit() );
    basket.setOrderRef( orderRef );
    basket.setStatus( BasketStatusEnum.ACTIVE );
    basket.setUserAccount( userAccount );

    return basketRepo.save( basket );
}

public String createOrderReference()
{
    return RandomStringUtils.random( 10, true, false ).toUpperCase();
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@MockBean` is a Spring annotation and is the one that should be used in integration tests in order to replace real bean with a mocked one:

> Annotation that can be used to add mocks to a Spring
>   ApplicationContext.

Mockitos `@Mock` creates a mock of that repository but does not inject that to the `BasketService`.

If you really need to used the Mockitos mocked version you would have to do it manually in the test:

```
@Mock
private BasketRepository basketRepo;

@Test
public void createBasketWithSameOrderRef() throws Exception
{
   basketService.setBasketRepository(basketRepo);
   ...
```

I wrote an article on [Mockito Stubbing](https://www.sourceartists.com/blog/unit-testing/mockito-stubbing/20) if you need a further read.

Comment: ah, I see it ! btw, I commented out first 2 when() - associated to basketRepo - and I get same result, basket is inserted. So that mean test is using @Autowired basketRepo instead of mocked one. Thanks